# $.validate.submitHandler error with ajax and php

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've a double form with jQuery Validate, but when the ajax call its supposed to be done, I get a error, `$.validate.submitHandrer` on `main.js`.

My code is next:

```
'use strict';
var titulo;
var email;
var keyword;
var landing;
var keyword2;
var landing2;
var medio;
var extra;

$("#form_pedido").validate({
    rules: {
        titulo: {
            required: true
        },
        keyword: {
            required: true
        },
        landing: {
            required: true
        }
    }, //fin rules
    messages: {
        email: {
            remote: "Este correo no esta registrado."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        //añadir aqui codigo ajax
        titulo = $('#titulo').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        keyword = $('#keyword').val();
        landing = $('#landing').val();
        keyword2 = $('#keyword2').val();
        landing2 = $('#landing2').val();
        medio = $('#periodico').val();
        extra = $('#texto').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'php/crear_publi.php',
            data: {
                email: email,
                keyword: keyword,
                landing: landing2,
                keyword2: keyword2,
                landing2: landing2,
                medio: medio,
                extra: extra
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#formulario").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            email: true,
            remote: "php/validar_email_db.php"
        },
    }, //fin rules
    messages: {
        email: {
            remote: "Este correo no esta registrado."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        $("#validar").click(function () {
            $("#form_pedido").fadeIn("fast", function () {
                $("#formulario").fadeOut("slow", function () {

                });
            });
        });
    }
});

//cargar medios en el select
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "php/listar_medios.php",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#periodico').empty();
        $.each(data, function () {
            $('#periodico').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(this.id_medio).html(this.nombre));
        });
    },
    complete: {}
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Por favor, solo letras");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("spanishlettersspace", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "Por favor, solo letras y espacios");
```

My php code, but I dont think this is the problem:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
/* Database connection information */
include("mysql.php" );
/*
 * AÑADIR MEDIOS!!!!
 */
function fatal_error($sErrorMessage = '') {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error');
    die($sErrorMessage);
}
/*
 * MySQL connection
 */
if (!$gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password'])) {
    fatal_error('Could not open connection to server');
}
if (!mysql_select_db($gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'])) {
    fatal_error('Could not select database ');
}
mysql_query('SET names utf8');
/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$titulo = $_GET["titulo"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$keyword = $_GET["keyword"];
$landing = $_GET["landing"];
$keyword2 = $_GET["keyword2"];
$landing2 = $_GET["landing2"];
$medio = $_GET["medio"];
$extra = $_GET["extra"];

$sql1 = "SELECT id_cliente
        FROM cliente
        where email1='".$email."'";

$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$id_cliente=$row1['id_cliente'];
}

$query1 = "insert into publirreportaje (titulo,fecha_inicio,fecha_modificacion,contenido,id_cliente,id_medio,tipo,palabraClave,url,palabraClave2,url2,infoExtra) values( 
             '". $titulo . "',
              NOW(),
              NOW(),
            '', 
              " .$id_cliente . ",
            " . $medio .",
            'publirreportaje',
            '".$keyword."',
            '".$landing."',
            '".$keyword2."',
            '".$landing2."',
            '".$extra."');" ;
 log($query1);
echo $query1;

$query_res1 = mysql_query($query1);
if($query_res1){

$sql = "SELECT id_contenido
        FROM publirreportaje
        where titulo='".$titulo."'";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$id_nuevo=$row['id_contenido'];
}
}
//echo "idenuevo =>  $id_nuevo";
for ($i=0;$i<count($editores);$i++)    
{     
//echo "<br> CLinicaid " . $i . ": " . $clinicas[$i];   
$query2 = "insert into publi_editor (id_publirreportaje,id_editor) values( 
             ". $id_nuevo . ", 
            " . $editores[$i] . ")" ;
//echo"$query1";
            $query_res2 = mysql_query($query2);
} 

if (!$query_res1||!$res||!$query_res2) {
   // $mensaje  = 'Error en la consulta de inserts: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
   // $estado = mysql_errno();
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        $mensaje = "Imposible añadir el articulo, num articulo ya existe";
        $estado = mysql_errno();
    } else {
        $mensaje = 'Error en la consulta: ' . mysql_error() ;
        $estado = mysql_errno();
    }
}
else
{
    $mensaje = "Insercion correcta";
    $estado = 0;
}
$resultado = array();
 $resultado[] = array(
      'mensaje' => $mensaje,
      'estado' => $estado
   );
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: You code is vulnerable to [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2257664).

Comment: which browser you used?

Comment: there is one trailing `,` after closing `rules>email` in second form it will cause issues in IE

Comment: @shaN,  only in VERY old versions of IE that nobody uses anymore... IE 7 and below.  Otherwise, I agree that trailing commas are sloppy but the OP likely just stripped out some superfluous code for posting.

Comment: So what is the exact error message??  It would also be ideal if you'd have taken the time to format your code for better readability.  And where is the ***rendered*** HTML of these two forms?

Comment: @Sparky sure it's, but i didnt post it for too much code :/

Comment: It's up to you to [make a **minimal** code example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  How are we supposed to find the mistake if we can't see it?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sparky the exact error message is main.js:45 $.validate.submitHandler

Comment: You never stated line 45 in your OP, but how exactly would we know which is line 45 inside your `main.js` file anyway?  Your console would show you line numbers.  You have to put more effort into asking the question.

Comment: @shaN, I know you were just trying to help, but your edit changed the OP's code.  Everyplace the OP had a `true`, your cleanup changed it into a `!0`.  I'll have to roll the whole thing back and re-edit.

Comment: @Sparky havent meant to cause any trouble, but `!0` is same as `true` right?

Comment: @shaN, yes, but who uses `!0` in place of `true`?  Cleaning up the code does not mean changing it into something else.  I simply used "tidyUp" within jsFiddle to fix indentations and spacing... not one character changed from the OP's original intent.

Comment: @Sparky line 45 is the ajax call: $.ajax({....

Comment: Which `ajax` call?  Your OP has three.  Getting the requisite information from you should not be this difficult.  Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You would absolutely never put a `click` handler inside the `submitHandler` function, and it's probably what's breaking things.

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $( "#validar" ).click(function() { // <- REMOVE
        $( "#form_pedido" ).fadeIn( "fast", function() {
            $( "#formulario" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {

            });
        });
    });   // <- REMOVE     
}
```

How can the `click` handler fire when the `submitHandler` is already capturing the click of the submit button?  The `submitHandler` fires when the `submit` button is clicked AND the form is valid.  With that `click` handler, nothing inside your `submitHandler` is going to do anything but sit there.

Otherwise, without seeing any of the HTML of your two forms, it's impossible to determine what other errors you've made.

---

You do not need to manually gather the value of every field...

```
submitHandler: function() {
    //añadir aqui codigo ajax
    email = $('#email').val();
    ....
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/crear_publi.php',
        data: {
            email: email,
            .... 

        }
....
```

Simply pass the `form` argument into the `submitHandler` and use jQuery `serialize()`...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/crear_publi.php',
        data: $(form).serialize()
....
```